# Neptlan secondary IP addresse Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, netplan, ip

I have to give my computer two IP addresses one to connect to the internet and one to reach other systems with pre-configuration IP addresses which i can‘t reach with my first IP address (different network range).

So my problem is if i configure my etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
 network:
 version: 2
 renderer: NetworkManager
 #renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
 enx9cebe81da444:
   addresses:
     - 192.168.1.38/24
     - 192.168.0.60/24
   gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

**ip -4 addr list** shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: enx9cebe81da444: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.38/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx9cebe81da444
       valid_lft 863284sec preferred_lft 863284sec
```

and set my renderer to NetworkManager i can connect to the internet but don‘t get my secondary IP-addresse.

Now when i switch the renderer to networkd i can get my secondary IP address and can reach my other IP addresses (both ranges) but i can‘t connect to the internet anymore.

```
network:
  version: 2
  #renderer: NetworkManager
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx9cebe81da444:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.38/24
        - 192.168.0.60/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

**ip -4 addr list** shows:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: enx9cebe81da444: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.38/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enx9cebe81da444
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.60/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enx9cebe81da444
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enx9cebe81da444 proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enx9cebe81da444 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.60 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enx9cebe81da444 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.38
```

ip neigh

```
192.168.1.1 dev enx9cebe81da444 lladdr 5c:49:79:75:42:e4 REACHABLE
```

addition:
From time to time the gateway is switching from reachable to stale.

Comment: Can you add output of `ip route` and `ip neigh` while using `networkd` as a renderer?